# How to use strstr to edit the result in C?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to use `strstr` to see if a string appears in another string. For example, I have a string like: `-path-elonmusk-bin`. I want to replace a part of it or `-path-elonmusk` to a `"$"`. So the updated path would be: `$/bin`.

I am able to change it to `"$"` but instead of changing the part, it changes the whole string. Is there a way to maybe split the string so it returns the rest of the path.

Here is my code:

```
char *home = "-path-elonmusk";
char *path = "-path-elonmusk-bin-asksks";
char *strmatching = strstr(path, home);

if(strmatching == path) {
strcpy(path, "~");
}
```

Comment: @Geo Aldana You may not change a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

Your code invokes undefined behavior, because you may not write into a string literal. You must allocate memory for it, since you can not know how long the inputstring will be.

```
if (match == path)
{
    size_t i = strlen(home);
    char *newstr = malloc(strlen(path) - i + 2);
    newstr[0] = '~';
    strcpy(&newstr[1], &path[i]);
    return newstr;
}

return NULL;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `path = "~";` do?

Comment: As I already said, you may not write to a string literal, and this would only change the first character anyway so you would get `~home/elonmusk...`

Comment: You're wrong. You are only changing the pointer to point to something else.

Comment: @alex01011, do you understand what `undefined berhavior`means? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: I doubt anything in what a wrote and the link had anything in common. GN

Comment: What is line 6 doing?  "strcpy(&newstr[1], &path{i]);"

Comment: It copies the string without the the match to the new string. You don't want the match in the resulting string, right? You should learn to use a debugger and examine what your code is doing. It should be `[i]` not `{i]` I fixed that.